# How to check if now (utc) is in time frame (according to time zone) in postgres

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, timezone, utc

I'm using postgres and I have these two tables:

```
             TIME_FRAMES
ID | TIME_ZONE | DAY_OF_WEEK | START | END | LECTURE_ID

      LECTURES
ID | CLASS | TEACHER
```

I want to run a query that fetches all lectures that takes place now (utc time of running the query).

I saw that there is a [list of time zones](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/static/timezones.html) Postgres supports so these values are the ones that I have persisted.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use date arithmetic:

```
SELECT *
FROM time_frames
WHERE current_timestamp BETWEEN
            (CAST (current_date || ' ' || start
                  AS timestamp without time zone
            ) AT TIME ZONE time_zone)
         AND
            (CAST (current_date || ' ' || "end"
                  AS timestamp without time zone
           ) AT TIME ZONE time_zone)
  AND extract(dow FROM current_date) = day_of_week;
```